# Difficulty with exercise 24.12 in Jech

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

**Exercise 24.12 in Jech's Set Theory (3d Millenium Edition): The lexicographical ordering $\omega \times {\omega}_1$ does not have true cofinality.**

True cofinality is defined (p.461) as the least cardinality of a cofinal *chain* (if it exists)
in a given partial order (P,<), i.e. of a subset of P linearly ordered by the order relation.

But why not just take $\omega \times {\omega}_1$ itself as the desired subset (with cardinality $\aleph_1$ of course)?  Surely it is a linearly ordered set, in the lexicographical order, which I take to mean $(a,b) < (c,d)$
if $a < c$, or $a = c$ and $b < d$.  Or does Jech perhaps have something else in mind for the lexicographical ordering?  (I have not managed to find his definition for it in the book.)

Comment: Linear orders have true cofinality, so Jech must have intended something different.

Comment: Yeah, now I am thinking it must be something like (a,b) < (c,d) means a< c and b < d.  Then it is clear that neither $\omega_1$ or $\omega$ will "work" as cardinalities for any cofinal chain.  I see in a book by W. Just and M. Weese they call this order on the Cartesian product the simple product ordering.